# "as" notation with TypeScript, need to export a namespace?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I have this TypeScript code:

```
import * as suman from 'suman';

const Test = suman.init(module,{
    ioc: {
        a: 'foo',
        b: 'far'
    } as suman.Ioc
});
```

As you can see I am trying to declare that the ioc object has a type of suman.Ioc (ioc object should "adhere to the Ioc interface"). But my IDE says "cannot find namespace 'suman'".

How can I create a type and reference it in my code in this scenario? I'd like to be able to reference the Ioc object type from the suman import if possible.

In other words, I don't want to do this all in the same file:

```
    declare namespace suman {

        interface Ioc {
             a: string,
             b: string
        }
    }


   import * as suman from 'suman';

    const Test = suman.init(module,{
       ioc: {
          a: 'foo',
          b: 'far'
        } as suman.Ioc  
    });
```

the reason is because I would then have to repeat the namespace declaration for every file like this which shouldn't be necessary (or advised).

Comment: is `suman` typed? If not, it does not have the `Ioc` interface and thus the error.

Comment: Also, not exactly sure what do you want to achieve by "trying to declare that the ioc object has a type of suman.Ioc". Can you elaborate?

Comment: suman is a regular node.js module. I have some type defs, but apparently they are not correct or in the wrong place. I am trying to achieve: to log errors/warnings if the object has properties that are not defined in the Ioc interface.

Comment: tbh, this is one of the more confusing questions I have ever asked on SO. I am confused, and I am trying to make at as easy as possible for the askees to not be as confused as I am, but not sure if it's working.

Comment: "log errors/warning..." this can only occurs during IDE/compile time. Is that what you need?

Comment: yes that's right, that's all I need, compile time errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`suman` is typed but the typed version is not release yet.

For now, you can installing it by `npm install sumanjs/suman` if you are comfortable to use the latest code.

If you want to use the latest release AND use the typings, you can consider using `typings` to install the typings file: `typings install suman=github:sumanjs/suman/lib/index.d.ts` and include `typings/index.d.ts` in your `tsconfig.json`.

As for `as suman.Ioc`, it is a way to tell the compiler that "hey, I know that you think this 'thing' is of some other type, but I would like you to treat it as 'suman.Ioc'".

That's why, even if the typings is there, it will not do what you wanted.

Luckily, the typings supplied by `suman` will be working fine for you.

Comment: huh, so I put it in the <angled> brackets, instead of using the "as" notation?

Comment: I am confused as to how the item in the <angled> brackets refers to the ioc object...what if I had two properties, ioc and foo? would it be <YourIocInterface, YourFooInterface>. I like the "as" notation, I wish it worked here.

Comment: `<angled>` is generics. Not type casting.

Comment: What is the signature of the init function?

Comment: The signature is here: https://github.com/sumanjs/suman/blob/rebase_branch/lib/index.d.ts

Comment: (module: NodeModule, opts: IInitOpts): ICreate;

Comment: `suman` is actually typed. You should be able to use `suman.Ioc`. Are you using TypeScript 2.0+?

Comment: right thanks, that's what I was thinking so I am confused why it wouldn't work. Yeah I am using TS2.2 right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138487/discussion-between-unional-and-alexander-mills).